# How i add field :name for Devise at user section?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, devise

I need to add Field :name to devise but i will try Create label,text field :name and add :name to devise model but my program is not show field :name.I don't Have any idea how to fix this?

Mycode in Model User

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :token_authenticatable, :confirmable,
  # :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  # Setup accessible (or protected) attributes for your model
  attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me, :name
  # attr_accessible :title, :body

  has_many :events, as: :eventable

  def to_s
    name.present? ? name : email
  end
end
```

and this is code in users/registrations/new.html.erb

```
<h2>Sign up</h2>

<%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
  <%= devise_error_messages! %>

  <div><%= f.label :name %><br />
  <%= f.text_field :name %></div>

  <div><%= f.label :email %><br />
  <%= f.email_field :email %></div>

  <div><%= f.label :password %><br />
  <%= f.password_field :password %></div>

  <div><%= f.label :password_confirmation %><br />
  <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation %></div>

  <div><%= f.submit "Sign up" %></div>
<% end %>

<%= render "devise/shared/links" %>
```

i try this but nothing happen.How i do that?

Answer (score 1):

Execute

```
$ rails generate devise:views users
```

That will generate `app/views/users` with all views inside.

Also make sure to change this line

```
config.scoped_views = false
```

to

```
config.scoped_views = true
```

inside `config/initializers/devise.rb` (line 189 for me) for devise to actually use the generated views.

Answer (score 0):

I see it now. Looks like your app displays wrong view. Use `rails generate devise:views users` command. I think that you made that view by you own, because path is wrong - `Users/registrations/new.html.erb` - 'Users' is unnecessarily camelized.

Comment: Oh im sorry The path in my Project is users/registrations/new.html.erb not 'Users' but i will try rails generate devise:views users it is nothing happen any idea?

Comment: `rails generate devise:views` should create `app/views/devise/registrations/new.html.erb`. To make sure which view is displayed, look into your logs. You can also paste it here if you will be confused.